# Bit-Band Alias Offset Address for TI MSP432P401 board

Tags: c, embedded, msp432, bit-banding

Would anyone explain, please, in this formula below for calculating Bit-Band Alias Offset Address for **TI MSP432P401R** board, why we should add to `(addr & 0xF0000000) + BB_OFFSET`, this value `((addr & 0xFFFFF) << 5)` ?

```cpp
#define TA0CTL_ADDR (0x40000000)

/* Bit Band Region is offset from Peripheral/SRAM */
#define BB_OFFSET (0x02000000)

/* Macro Function to Read Memory */
#define HWREG32(addr)  (*((volatile uint32_t *)(addr)))

#define BITBAND_ADDR(addr, bit) ( (addr & 0xF0000000) + BB_OFFSET + ((addr & 0xFFFFF) << 5) + (bit << 2) )
```

If the `addr` variable in case of **MSP432** has the size of the `word == uint32_t`. It means, that:

1. `(addr & 0xF0000000) + BB_OFFSET  = 0x42000000`
2. and then: `(bit << 2) = 0x00000002`
3. and the alias will be simply: `0x42000000 + 0x00000002 = 0x42000002` ?
   So, I come up with my question: why we also need to add `((addr & 0xFFFFF) << 5)` to `(addr & 0xF0000000) + BB_OFFSET` ?

Am I wrong with my calculations ?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each bit of the bit-bandable regular address space maps to a 32 bit location in the bit-band region.

The `(addr & 0xFFFFF)` part masks lower order address bits to get the 32-bit *word offset* from the start of the bit-bandable regular address region. The `<< 5` part multiplies the offset by 32 to obtain the *bit-offset* of the least-significant bit of `addr` in the bit-band region.

For an explanation of how bit-band addresses map to regular addresses see [Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual - Bit-Banding](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100166/0001/Programmers-Model/Bit-banding/About-bit-banding).

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the link !